# How to filter order list by shipping method?

Tags: php, magento

I try to create custom grid with orders shipped by some shipping method (for example TNT). Here is a method where should be a filter:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I'm going to use something like addFieldToFilter(), but I don't know field name. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "shipping_method" or "shipping_description".
this fields are from "sales_flat_order"

Comment: Thanks! The solution is: $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order.entity_id', array('sales_flat_order'=>'shipping_method'), null, 'left');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_method', '***');

Comment: Or even better solution: $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'shipping_method="***" AND main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order.entity_id', false, null, 'inner');

Answer (score 0):

I've made [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/OSdave/extension/5814/orders_grid_payment_shipping_filters) which allows you to filter the admin orders grid by shipping and payment methods. give it a try :)

Comment: Cool, it's really useful extension and I'll use it regardless of my current question which is already solved ;) Thank you.

Comment: your extension is not working in 1.7.0.2. can you name free extension which can work on 1.7.0.2